# Line integral of a vector

Tags: integration, vectors, line-integrals

Let C be the part of the plane curve defined by $$y^2=x^3-x$$ between $$(\frac{-1}{\sqrt3},\sqrt[4]{\frac4{27}})$$ and $$(0,0)$$ oriented from left to right. How would I calculate

$$\int_{C}y^2\vec{i}+(2xy+4y^3e^{y^4})\vec{j}ds$$

I have already found that the vector field is conservative, I'm just not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: Since it is conservative, you don't have to use the path they give you - this is path independence

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes, however, I'm not sure what the set up integral will look like

Comment: Wait a second, as written none of the theorems involving conservativeness apply, this is not a "vector" line integral, its two scalar integrals put together in a vector.

Comment: @NinadMunshi so how exactly would I solve this

Comment: You need to check the problem to see if this is exactly what is written. Because this problem would have had a nice solution if it was a vector line integral, which it is not.

Comment: This is how the problem was written but assuming it's a mistake and this is a vector line integral, how would I set up the integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the vector field is conservative it has a potential function. Check that the gradient of

$$f(x,y) = xy^2 + e^{y^4}$$

is indeed the vector field in the problem. Then use the fundamental theorem of line integrals:

$$\int_{\vec{a}}^{\vec{b}}\nabla f \cdot d\vec{r} = f(\vec{b}) - f(\vec{a})$$

to get that the integral equals

$$f(0,0) - f\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\sqrt[4]{\frac{4}{27}}\right) = \frac{11}{9} - e^{\frac{4}{27}} $$

Answer (score 0):

${\bf F}(x,y)=(y^2,2xy+4y^3e^{y^4})$ is the vector field. If ${\bf F}$ is conservative then ${\bf F}=\nabla G$ for some scalar field $G(x,y)$. And,
$$
\int_C {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r} = \int_a^b {\bf F}({\bf r}(t))\cdot {\bf r}'(t)dt
=G({\bf r}(b))-G({\bf r}(a))
$$
where ${\bf r}(t)$ is any parametrisation of the curve $C$. We have the endpoints ${\bf r}(b)$ and ${\bf r}(a)$ so we only need to find $G$.

${\bf F}=\nabla G$ means that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}&=&y^2 \qquad and \qquad \frac{\partial G}{\partial y}=2xy+4y^3e^{y^4}\\
\implies G&=&xy^2+f(y)+C\qquad and \qquad G=xy^2+e^{y^4}+g(x)+C
\end{eqnarray*}
for some functions $f(y)$ and $g(x)$. So, take $f(y)=e^{y^4}$ and $g(x)=0$ and we have $G(x,y)=xy^2+e^{y^4}+C$.

Now, 
$$
\int_C {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r} = G({\bf r}(b))-G({\bf r}(a)) = 
G(0,0)-G\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\sqrt{\frac{4}{27}}\right)
$$